# Is there a way to have BBEdit automatically save files when switching to a different application?

Tags: macos, text-editor

In Sublime Text 2, there is a `save_on_focus_lost` preference option. When set, every time you switch  to another app all current files are saved. Is there a way to make BBEdit behave the same way?

Answer (score 4):

BBEdit has "Attachement Point" scripts that are automatically run during different conditions. Here is a list of Attachment Points:

http://www.bbeditextras.org/wiki/index.php?title=Attachment_Points

Here is a script that should do what you want:

https://gist.github.com/benspaulding/1287814

Answer (score -1):

I think the answer is No, I lost most of the edit for the last few months, I am not used to saving files as most of the editor does auto same nowadays, please add the feature as soon as possible.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.   The other answer pretty conclusively shows this is possible and unlimited undo / redo might also save your work.  Also, don’t confuse us for Apple support or BBEdit support - We’re a volunteer site for mutual assistance.